# Visual Studio is deleting PCH file in shared PCH solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been trying to get a single PCH project working for a while now, but the .pch file I generate keeps getting deleted.

Project Structure:

```
Solution.sln
|
| Build.props
| pch.props
|
| - Lib
|    | - src
|    |    | main.cpp
|
|
| - SharedPch
|    | -src
|    |    | pch.cpp
|    |    | pch.hpp
|
```

Build.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">

    <OutBuildName>$(Platform)-$(Configuration)</OutBuildName>
    <OutBuildDir>$(SolutionDir)Build\$(OutBuildName)\$(ProjectName)\</OutBuildDir>
    <OutBuildParentDir>$(SolutionDir)Build\$(OutBuildName)\</OutBuildParentDir>

    <SharedPchDir>$(SolutionDir)Build\Shared\$(OutBuildName)\</SharedPchDir>
    <SharedPch>$(SharedPchDir)SharedPCH.pch</SharedPch>
    <SharedPdb>$(OutBuildParentDir)SharedPCH.pdb</SharedPdb>
    <SharedIdb>$(OutBuildParentDir)SharedPCH.idb</SharedIdb>

  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutDir>$(OutBuildDir)</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(OutBuildDir)Intermediates\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(SolutionDir)SharedPCH\src;$(ProjectDir)\src;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>$(SharedPch)</PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

pch.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomBuildBeforeTargets>ClCompile</CustomBuildBeforeTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <CustomBuildStep>
      <Command>
        if EXIST "$(SharedPdb)" xcopy /Y /F "$(SharedPdb)" "$(IntDir)"
        if EXIST "$(SharedIdb)" xcopy /Y /F "$(SharedIdb)" "$(IntDir)"
      </Command>
      <Outputs>$(IntDir)SharedPCH.pdb</Outputs>
      <Inputs>$(SharedPdb)</Inputs>
    </CustomBuildStep>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

pch.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
```

pch.cpp

```
#include "pch.hpp"
```

main.cpp

```
#include "pch.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Lib is set to use (/Yu) pch.hpp
SharedPch is set ot Create (/Yc) pch.hpp.

Code is based off: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/shared-pch-usage-sample-in-visual-studio/

The files are successfully copied to the shared directory, the project works when compiled with C7 comparability.
The .pch is generated perfectly fine using SharedPch, however when I build lib, the .pch gets deleted!

Comment: Are you sure that `SharedPch` and `Lib` project have the same set of preprocessor directives and other settings? If lib is a static library then `SharedPch` should also be a static library. They also need to use the same toolkit and so on. To my opinion shared pch is not worth the time spent on it and it would be better to keep things simple and create one pch per project.

Comment: @VTT Made both a static lib, Didn't work. Haven't done much with preprocessor, Both using same toolkit & sdk.